# Impact of using lambda as a local helper method

Tags: c++, lambda

In a method of a class, I need an helper, but only in this method. I don't want this helper method to de declared in my class or anywhere else as this is the only specific place I am using it.
So I thought about local lambda, I have doubts about the performance. Is there a difference ? Or maybe another way to not to pollute my class API.

Here is with static helper as class member

```
class Dummy1{
public:
   Dummy1(){
      helper();
   }
   static void helper(){
      std::cout <<"helper"<<std::endl;
   }
};
```

Here is with local lambda

```
class Dummy2{
public:
   Dummy2(){
      std::function<void(void)> helper = [](){std::cout <<"helper"<<std::endl;};
      helper();
   }
};
```

Comment: Replace `std::function<void(void)> helper = ...` with `auto helper = ...`

Comment: Or even `[](){ std::cout <<"helper"<<std::endl; }();` no need for a local.

Comment: there is no reason to expect this to have negative impact on performance. Unless you actually measured a difference in a real case.

Comment: @RichardCritten Yes I'm using auto, this is just for a clean example here. And yes I "need" a local because I need to call this lambda multiple times

Comment: first use `auto helper = `. Storing a lambda in a function is yet another bit of overhead.
Then use `static auto helper = ` to only make an instance once. And calling `helper()` is an extra function call too. However your code doesn't show why you would need a lambda in the first place.

Comment: converting to `std::function` does not make it "clean", it rather adds a big "wtf" to the code. `std::function` is not just "a function". It is a type erased function object that you use when you need the type erasure, otherwise you dont need `std::function`

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number Yup :)

Comment: You can also just have it in unnamed namespace in your cpp where you need to use it, it's just the matter of coding style. For the moment forget about performance impact unless you actually measured that this makes a difference. Compiler is allowed to inline small functions in any case.

Comment: Why do you want to do this at all? In the example you present in the question I don't see any benefit using an extra function/lambda/whatever instead of simply writing the code in the constructor body directly. Are you actually passing this object as a functor to some other function?

Comment: The biggest performance killer in that code is `std::endl`. Do you really need the extra stuff that it does? `'\n'` ends a line.